# How to use Laravel @can() in Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-permission

I have a project that is fully Laravel-8 using Spatie-Permission. Everything is working well.

But the team decided to use Laravel-8 as backend and Angular-11 as front-end.

Initially, in the pure Laravel, it looks like this:

Controller

```
public function index()
{
     if (! Gate::allows('role_access')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $roles = Role::all();

    return view('admin.roles.index', compact('roles'));
}
```

view blade:

```html
@can('role_access')
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="{{ route(" admin.roles.index ") }}" class="nav-link {{ request()->is('admin/roles') || request()->is('admin/roles/*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-briefcase"></i>
    <p>
      Role
    </p>
  </a>
</li>
@endcan
```

Now that I've transformed the front-end into Angular, I have:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if(!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('role_access'))
        return response()->json([ "message" => 'User do not have permission'], 401);
    if(($request->get('sort')!='null' && $request->get('sort')!='') && $request->get('search')) {
        $role = Role::with('permissions')->where("name", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('search')}%")->orderby($request->get('sort'), $request->get('order'))->paginate(10);
    } else if(($request->get('sort')!='null' && $request->get('sort')!='')){
        $role = Role::with('permissions')->orderby($request->get('sort'), $request->get('order'))->paginate(10);
    }
    else if($request->get('search'))
        $role = Role::with('permissions')->where("name", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('search')}%")->paginate(10);
    else
        $role = Role::with('permissions')->paginate(10);
    return response()->json($role, 200);
}
```

When it was purely Laravel, I used @can() for the aspect users should only see. For instance only users with that have permission to role_access will see it.

How do I transform @can() in Laravel view blade into Angular?

Thanks

Comment: i think you can make a helper in angular from permission array of user

Comment: @KamleshPaul - How? Kindly guide. Thanks

Comment: can you get user permission in array list ? in controller once loged in

Comment: @KamleshPaul - Yes, I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all the permission from login user like this

```php
$permissions = auth()->user()?->role()->with('permissions')->get()
    ->pluck('permissions')
    ->flatten()
    ->pluck('name')
    ->toArray();
return $permissions;
```

then in javascript side `angular ,react or vuejs` you can create a helper like this

```js
const can = (permissions, can) => {
    if (permissions) {
        return permissions.some(r => can.includes(r))
    }

    return false;
};
```

then you can use anywhere `can(permissions,'read_pust')` here `permissions` is get from server and store in cookie or localstorage

> EX: i use this `v-if="$helpers.can(permissions, ['node_read'])"` this in vuejs you can create helper like this

Comment: Sorry for this last question. Do I need to still use ngIf can() in Angular component.html as I did in Laravel?

Comment: yes if you want to hide something then you can use `ngif="can(allpremissions,['read'])"`

Comment: Can you give me a detail example? Thanks