# Role and Permission in Vue SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two separate projects. One is Laravel for RESTful API and the other is Vue SPA.

If the frontend is also handled by Laravel, then handling role and permissions is easy since we can use the can() and hasRole() method Spatie Permission provided.

However, we can't access this value in Vue SPA directly from the backend.

Is there any way I can control the permission in Vue SPA?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you tried already?

Comment: you should try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984962/how-to-use-laravel-can-in-angular/66985283#66985283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send to the client, after a successful login, the user' data plus his roles and permissions, and create a Vue component named `Can`, for example, that only show something if the user has the role or permission to do so.

```html
<can permission="post.delete">
  <v-btn>Delete record</v-btn>
<can>
```

The Can component access the user data (which includes his roles and permissions) and check if the user has the ability to see the underlying content.

Comment: How do I control synchronization with laravel backend. I mean what if admin changes some permissions of authenticated user before the user logout ?? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use websockets (broadcast) or an approach called stale-while-revalidate to keep the user data in sync. For Vue.js there is libray called [vswr](https://github.com/Kong/swrv) that can help you achieve that.